# Validating inline radio buttons in Bootstrap 5.1

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrap-5

I have a form that requires validation and works fine for text and textareas but not for inline radio buttons.

```
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate method="POST">
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1" required>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2" required>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">2</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3" required>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">3</label>
</div>
<div class="invalid-feedback">
    Radio button is required.
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Validate</button>
</form>
```

I see that the controls and labels turn red when submitted but the text in the invalid-feedback is not there. I also want it to be aligned all the way to the left.

Comment: I don't see a specific example for this on the docs, however they do have one for radios. In that, they put the `invalid-feedback` text div within the last radio `form-check` div. So maybe try that? Move your `invalid-feedback` div at the end of the last (3rd here) `form-check` div.

Comment: That works but it goes under the 3rd radio button and not all of them so it's not aligned all the way to the left.

Comment: As I see now, it isn't possible in this way. Please refer to the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48702258/bootstrap-4-radio-validation
It's for B4, but should work similarly for B5 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS class to your document:

```css
.was-validated :invalid~.invalid-feedback {
  display: inline;
}
```

This way you override the `display: block` that is applied to the `invalid-feedback` after the form is submitted, and the validation message is displayed inline, aligned with the rest inline objects.